# Search for Q-ID (from Wikidata) with Twitter Username ID. (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

I have a list of verified Twitter User-IDs.

```
data['screen_name'] = [MOFAJapan_en, serenawilliams, JeffBezos ....]
data['twitter_ids'] =  [303735625, 26589987, 15506669 ....]
```

and I want to get their respective Q-IDs from Wikidata. For the above Twitter-username-IDs, it will look sort of like this:

```
q_id_list = [Q222241, Q11459, Q312556 ....]
```

I ran into a slight complication here: if you search for MOFAJapan_en or MOFA of Japan, Wikidata API cannot recognize it. However, MOFAJapan has a [wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q222241).

[image: example wikidata entity for Twitter ID]

I know that the Property # for Twitter username is P2002, but how do I query for this without knowing the Q-ID?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you have added both tags: Do you use the API or the SPARQL endpoint? Can you [edit] your question to include the way you’ve tried?

Comment: @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions either one is fine, but I'm making an API call right now using python-requests. I also found Q-id from google search API and then got the wiki data page with that Q-id, however, it's not working well. Just need to search for Q-id based on twitter username id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of Twitter names (inside `VALUES`), this SPARQL query will find the persons:

```
SELECT ?twitterName ?person
WHERE {

  VALUES ?twitterName {
    "MOFAJapan_en"
    "serenawilliams"
    "JeffBezos"
  }

  ?person wdt:P2002 ?twitterName .
  
}
```

It won’t find anything for `MOFAJapan_en`, as the correct value seems to be `MofaJapan_en`. To ignore case, you can use a `FILTER` with `LCASE`, but this will increase runtime performance:

```
SELECT ?twitterName ?person
WHERE {

  VALUES ?twitterName_anyCase {
    "MOFAJapan_en"
    "serenawilliams"
    "JeffBezos"
  }
  
  FILTER( LCASE(?twitterName_anyCase) = LCASE(?twitterName) ) .

  ?person wdt:P2002 ?twitterName .
  
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Stefan - brox IT-Solutions. This worked great.